# Name 'Ridge' is not defined in Python Spyder

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, spyder

I have installed scikit learn and other dependancies in the conda environment snowflakes.

I type the following starter code

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)
clf.fit ([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1]) 
Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
      normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

clf.predict([1,1])
```

This yields the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sridhar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/sridhar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/home/sridhar/anaconda3/envs/snowflakes/Test/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
NameError: name 'Ridge' is not defined
```

What do i make of this? I have all dependencies installed as conda list shows them all.

Comment: Doing this gives /home/sridhar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
>>> But i havent used a 1d array?

Comment: Infact there is a warning mark saying sklearn imported but unused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it's working fine:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: import sklearn

In [6]: from sklearn import linear_model

In [7]: clf = linear_model.Ridge (alpha = .5)

In [8]: clf.fit ([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1])
Out[8]: 
Ridge(alpha=0.5, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

In [9]: clf.predict([[1,1]])
Out[9]: [ 0.82727273]
```

Seems that you must have copied that code from an Ipython notebook, where it prints the output automatically if there exists.

Hence, it throws the error as `Ridge` is no where defined in the import statements.

If you truly want to run this in Spyder, I consider using `print(clf.fit ([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, .1, 1]))` and remove the below lines altogether.

Comment: After adding from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge i  get /home/sridhar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:‌​386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning) >

Comment: there is actually a warning symbol saying sklearn imported but not used!